# Using $ref to access child elements?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a list with a `$ref` on the `ul`:

```
<ul ref="list">
    <li></li>
    ....
```

Is there a way to access all the `li` by using `this.$refs.list`?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to access the children of the `ref`.

Something like this.

`this.$refs.list.children....`